# Python - deq function prints out 8 times - prevent to print only once?

Tags: python, deque

So I have played abit with deq and almost come up to the finish but there was on concerned that it is printing 8 times due to the length of the deq while I just want it to print out once.

What I have done is:

```
old_list = []
deq = deque(old_list, maxlen=8)
url = 'https://www.supremecommunity.com/restocks/eu/'

while True:
    try:
        new_list = []

        bs4 = soup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

        for item in bs4.findAll('div', {'class': 'restock-item'}):
            if item.find('div', {'class': 'user-detail'}):
                name = item.find('h5', {'class': 'handle restock-name'}).string
                color = item.find('h6', {'class': 'restock-colorway'}).string

                new_list.append(name + color)

        for newitem in new_list:
            if newitem not in deq:
                print(name)
                print(color)
                deq.append(newitem)

            else:
                print('Sleeping 5 sec')
                time.sleep(5)
    except:
        continue
```

Basically it checks the website and prints out **name and color** and then add it to the list of deq. However my output prints out 8 times of the same name and color because of the maxlen=8 and my **question** is:

How can I make it so it prints out only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always printing the same variables `name` and `color` as they where lastly defined in the `for`-loop above.

```
      name = item.find('h5', {'class': 'handle restock-name'}).string
      color = item.find('h6', {'class': 'restock-colorway'}).string
```

As you are printing `print(name)` and `print(color)` in your second `for`-loop it always refers to the last values that `name` and `color` had.

To solve this you should refer to the variable `newitem` in your printing statements.

**EDIT:**

Here you are just concatenating the two strings.

```
new_list.append(name + color)
```

I suggest that you make it a list of lists.

```
new_list.append([name,color])
```

You can then use `print(newitem[0])` and `print(newitem[1])` to print the different names and colors.

Comment: Oh, That is actually true... is there any other way to solve it by not newitem, where I just want to print out `name and color` separated?

Comment: This helped and I appreciate it alot!